# is there any packages to get e-mail/g-mail behind a proxy (kerio proxy not socks) in node js?

Tags: node.js, proxy, imap, node-imap

I want to get my e-mail/g-mail in node-js server. I've found the Imap and node-imap but they are not support proxy.
can somebody help me?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

[ImapFlow](https://imapflow.com/) module supports proxies. When setting it up add `proxy:"socks5://…"` property to the config to enable it.